# Implementing specialized data structures in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl

(Okay, so my previous question is on hold as being too broad, so I'm narrowing it down here.)

I'm looking to take part in algorithmic programming contests, and a lot of problems hinge on the use of specialized data structures which are extremely good at a certain operation - for example, Fenwick trees allow calculation of prefix sums of a list of values in logarithmic time.

What is the preferred way of implementing such data structures in **modern** C++ (i.e. using C++11 features)? Is it possible to use STL algorithms and containers instead of writing `struct`s and coding every operation by hand?

I'm looking for Fenwick trees, segment trees, treaps and some other data structures often useful in IOI-style contests, but general strategies are more than enough.

Comment: Why do you put special emphasis on modern C++? What new language construct or standard library enhancement do you have in mind that would make a difference?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I may be wrong, but as far as I know C++11 introduces a lot of new STL algorithms that make some things easier, such as [some shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).

Comment: @PeterSchneider my point was that answers should preferably exploit everything C++11 has to offer.

Answer (score 3):

there's an implementation of a fenwick tree here: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Fenwick_tree

It uses std::vector as the underlying container.
arguably the method `increase` could be written in terms of `std::transform` or `std::foreach`.

Comment: Thank you; this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.